# convert serialized data to array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I pulled serialized data from database table and i want to display it on array. `a:7:{i:0;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:6;s:10: »user_value »;s:4: »jack »;}i:1;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:7;s:10: »user_value »;s:5: »david »;}i:2;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:8;s:10: »user_value »;s:5: »45587″;}i:3;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:9;s:10: »user_value »;s:3: »447″;}i:4;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:10;s:10: »user_value »;s:3: »115″;}i:5;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:11;s:10: »user_value »;s:6: »Agadir »;}i:6;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:13;s:10: »user_value »;s:0: » »;}}`
Update:Thanks guys, i tried unserialize but it is not working. I fond somewhere that unserialize doesn't work with ':;," and i should use a uncode function.   My question is how can i do all that in same time: uncode>>unserialize>>store in Table or array

Comment: It's seems improper serialize string. Though you can use [*unserialize*](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to converts it back into a PHP value.

Comment: @Simlali, What are the values you are trying to attempt to get from that. ? `unserialize()` fails here though.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i have a ninja form where i am supposed to fill it. i am trying to get this records from the database and display it on a custom table. the table  called vl21i_ninja_forms_subs and the field is $data.

Comment: @Simlali, I get you but your serialized data is kinda broken..

Comment: here is a the link http://lahbib.x27.us/liste/

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran help please

Comment: @Simlali, I am stumbled because that data is not valid :(

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran did you checked the page, it's a whatever hostin just for the test

Comment: @Simlali, Yeah I checked the page. How are you getting the data ? Did you serialize it or it is already available ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it's already serialized, ninja forms generate those fields. i tried before customize the table where it  stocks the data. yet i am a "very" beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found what i needed here `

```
$json_data = [];
foreach ($subs as $sub_id => $sub) {
    $submission_data = array(); 
    $data = unserialize($sub['data']);
    $user_values = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $user_values[$value['field_id']] = $value['user_value'];
    }

    foreach ( $fields as $field_id => $field ) {
        $user_value = $user_values[$field['id']];
        if ($user_value == '') { 
            continue;
        }

        $submission_data[] = array(
            "label" => $field['data']['label'],
            "value" => $user_value,
            "type" => $field['type']
        );
    }

    $json_data[] = array(
            "id" => $sub['id'],
            "items" => array_values($submission_data)
        );

    echo json_encode(array_values($json_data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}`
```

from this  [link](http://www.jurecuhalev.com/blog/2014/01/29/results-of-wordpress-ninja-forms-entries-as-json/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$x=unserialize($serialized_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress system has very neat [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) for dealing with serialized data, it is called
`maybe_unserialize()`.

The function will unserialize value **only if it was serialized** ,the check for serialized data is done automatically, so this will spare you some time.

```
<?php maybe_unserialize( $original ) ?>
```

**Parameters**

`$original` - string and it is required, maybe unserialized original, if is needed.

**Return Values**

Unserialized data can be any type.

Answer (score 0):

This following code worked in my case as, I have serialized by jquery, then assign it to an input as a string and submitting the form.Then getting data on the PHP.

```
parse_str($_POST, $allFormData);
print_r($allFormData['data']);
```